# Make a ScrollView take all space available - Android

Tags: android

I have a `ConstraintLayout` in which I have an image at the top and an action bar at the bottom that should both stay fixed. I have a `ScrollView` between them, and I want it to take all the space available between the image at the top and the action bar at the bottom. However, I tried using `height=wrap_content` but then the `ScrollView` gets displayed on top of the other components, and I didn't find any way other than fixing a `height` attribute. Still, then it's not dynamic anymore and it doesn't go to the bottom even though there's space available.

How should I go about doing that? Thanks in advance, here's the code of my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/popup_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/popup_show_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        tools:src="@drawable/default_show_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/popup_show_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/popup_action_bar"
        android:padding="@dimen/default_margin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- ScrollView content -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/popup_action_bar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <!-- Action bar icons -->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: On your `ScrollView`, replace `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` with `android:layout_height="0dp"`. Have the `LinearLayout` inside of it use `match_parent` for its height.

Comment: I tried doing that but my `ScrollView` then just has a height of `0dp` and doesn't show.

Comment: Did you already try setting `android:layout_height="match_parent"` on `popup_layout`?

Comment: Yes but that doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Does this have a parent layout? Please show it if has. It can cause it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout inside the `ScrollView` needs to have a height of `wrap_content`, so it's sized to the contents (which can be bigger than the `ScrollView` "window", moving the contents layer up and down is what allows it to scroll).

Your `ScrollView` needs to have `layout_height="0dp"` so it uses the vertical constraints to determine its height, which will be sized so it fills the space between the two views you've constrained it to. This is the size of the "window" into the scrollable content. It should never be `wrap_content` because that defeats the purpose of having a smaller window into a larger content layer!

The parent `ConstraintLayout` (`popup_layout`) needs to have either a fixed height, or `match_parent`, so it actually creates that extra space for the `ScrollView` to live in - i.e. it needs to be taller than the image + the action bar. If you want to make it `wrap_content`, then the `ScrollView` needs to have a fixed height too, so that's taken into account when sizing the parent layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/popup_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/popup_show_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/popup_show_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/popup_action_bar"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lines="100"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:text="bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla "
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/popup_action_bar"
        android:background="#FFCC22"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <!-- Action bar icons -->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can use the *Layout Inspector* in Android Studio to see what your view hierarchy looks like while it's running, and make sure everything's where it should be and sized correctly:

[image: The Layout Inspector showing the working layout, with the ScrollView and its content layer outlined]

You can see the `ScrollView` window there, with the larger content layout slid up a bit behind it ("scrolled down")

Comment: That was a perfect answer, thanks ! I ended up using a fixed height for my ScrollView but I may change my parent layout to `match_parent` and use the `0dp` ScrollView height as that seems like a better approach

Comment: @Balizok yeah generally you'd want a scrollview that takes up the remaining screen space in your layout, so the rest of the screen is used to display content and it can scroll if there's more content than it can show. But sometimes you might just want a smaller area (say in the middle of a form that the user needs to fill out) where you want a bunch of scrollable stuff, but in a fixed-height box that doesn't take up too much room, and the user can easily skip past- depends what you need! Don't forget there's a `layout_constraintHeight_min` property too, in case you want to carve out some space